# How Do I get detailed printer Informations in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

The JavaFX class `Printer` offers the method `showPrintDialog()`. This dialog displays detailed data about the selected printer (type, location, comment).

[image: showPrintDialog]

I intend to display this information in a different context. Does anyone know how to get this information?

Comment: Look into `PrinterJob.getJobSettings()`

Comment: I have tried this before but I do not get the informations I'd like to have (type, location), do I?

Comment: Yeah, it's how I get the printers and their names. I still don't get the type, location and comments. I looked at the API, but there are no methods to get these values - at least not in `javafx.print`. However, there must be a way to get this data, because it's obviously displayed in the dialog. But I can't find the method calls in the JavaFX source code that do exactly that.

Comment: I have done some digging and I can't find anything I think because `showPrintDialog()` uses the os native print widow it has access to that information at least for Type and Location I can find the rest of the items(Page Range Copies Collate...) in the os native window but that doesnt seem to be what your looking for maybe try to step out of the Javafx printing and see if any normal print classes can pull that information then you can compare them by name and go from there

Comment: I have come to a similar conclusion. I had hoped to find another idea here, but it seems as if I had to try something else. Swing/AWT hasn't got me any further yet. I'll see if I can find another framework.

Anyway, thanks for the help. As soon as I have found a solution, I will post it here.